# Fullscreen video in background on Login

Tags: html, css, video, mp4

Hello can anyone help me with that.
I want to have video in background in my login form

this is my index.html
http://pastebin.com/UttJKqdM

and this is my style.css
http://pastebin.com/AhHwn0fH

Please help me :C

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin, like this: http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/

Trying to do this from scratch is not worth the effort when others have done such a great job!

Answer (score 0):

To have the video in the background fullscreen, apply `height:100% ; width:100%` to video-bg. After that, you would probably want to set the z-index of the video lower than the login div. In the end : [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psvpLf5f/)

The black is the video, since I don't have the file. Best of luck to you.